Replacement for Asetek 240mm 570LX AIO cpu cooler that uses the same intel backplate
I need to replace my CPU cooler, but I cannot remove the backplate of the old CPU cooler from the motherboard (glued).
The general question is: How do I find CPU AIO water coolers that are compatible with a particular model of backplate?
If that is too general, then maybe somebody can address my particular situation: I need to know which models of CPU water coolers can use the same Intel backplate as the Asetek 240mm 570LX. The processor is an Intel Core i7-5820K Processor, so the socket is LGA2011-3. I know Asetek products get rebranded by other companies, but I haven't been able to find a resource that matches compatible models.

Before anything else...
A gentle reminder that LGA 2011-3 is not designed to have a removable backplate. There are threads built into the front of the retention mechanism, which the cooler is designed to screw into.

Assuming that this is the only thing that's not removable on your motherboard, any Socket 2011-compatible cooler should work fine. PCPartPicker can easily provide a list of such coolers, and we can help recommend one here if you want.
If however, there is some other nonstandard part of the mounting and retention mechanism that is not removable on your motherboard...
I'll recommend the Thermaltake Floe DX RGB 240 TT Premium Edition - $112.85

The Asetek 240mm 570LX is part of Asetek's 4th generation of CPU AIOs. As you're aware, a number of brands, including Corsair and Thermaltake, used Asetek designs for their own coolers. Fun fact: this is largely a consequence of Asetek owning a number of important patents related to water cooling, which has resulted in quite a bit of litigation over the years.
Unfortunately, while the 4th generation was incredible popular, it's closing in on 10 years old at this point. Asetek is currently on their 8th generation of pump tech, with a 9th gen probably coming reasonably soon. Unsurprisingly, newer Asetek AIOs don't use the same mounting mechanism; while 4th and 5th gen pumps use the same retention mechanism, the 6th gen introduced a simpler (but incompatible) design.
That means it's pretty hard to find anyone producing new AIOs with compatible mounting at this point. While you could buy a used AIO, I would generally advise against it; as much as I advocate for used PC hardware, AIOs are notoriously unreliable (especially as they age).
As far as I can tell, the Thermaltake Floe DX is the only remaining AIO on the market that's available new (for a reasonable sum of money) that still uses the Asetek 4th generation mounting system.
There are two key caveats to this:

I don't have access to a definitive list of 4th or 5th gen Asetek coolers. While Asetek did helpfully provide a partial list last year of 8th, 7th, and 6th gen coolers, no 5th or 4th gen coolers are listed (presumably because hardly anyone is making new coolers with that old tech.) My search is based on a review of PCPartPicker filtered by known current and former Asetek partners + my own recall, which is limited. There may be other models out there still in production (or with substantial new-old stock), but I don't know of them.
While I am confident that the Floe DX is an Asetek design, I am not 100% sure it's compatible with your backplate. The manual clearly shows that it uses the 4th gen mounting system, not the 6th gen, but there is a tiny possibility that something may be slightly different and causes problems. Amazon has free returns though.


Thank you for the great answer.  I didn't realize that the LGA 2011-3 was designed so that the backplate is nonremovable, but it does explain why I couldn't remove it.  As you said, there are threads in the front of the retention mechanism, which the cooler needs to screw into.  I don't specifically need it to use the same assembly chassis, as long as the one it comes with is compatible with screwing into those threads.

I think the Thermalright Frozen Edge 240 is good for me.  It doesn't have those LEDs that I don't use anyway, and it's cheap.  I'm in Japan, so I have to find one available here.  The Japanese Amazon site says this model is compatible with 2011, but doesn't say 2011-3.  But Thermalright's says it works with 2011-3 too., so it should be fine.  Can I assume it includes the needed mounting rig?  Thermal paste?

Thermalright has great stuff for the money, I'd recommend the Frozen Edge 240 if you can find it for a good price. I'm not too familiar with Japanese retailers, but Kakaku says that it's on Rakuten. ¥10,000 is a little high compared to the US, but still seems cheaper than most anyone else. If you want to go the air cooling route, the Thermalright Peerless Assassin and Deepcool AK620 are also great value, and should be fine for a 5820K up to about 4.4 GHz.

Socket 2011 and 2011-3 are mechanically identical, any cooler that works on one will work on the other. (Caveat: there's a weird, server-only variant called "Narrow ILM", but you won't have to worry about that for any consumer-grade parts.) Any cooler you buy new should come with included thermal paste, so I probably wouldn't worry about buying extra unless you're reaaaaaaalllllyyyy trying to maximize thermal performance.
Funny enough I happen to be in Japan at the moment too, so let me know if you find any good deals-hunting websites!

Thanks, This morning I installed the Notte Cooler that I had already bought. Before I didn't understand the mounting because it came with a different backplate and attachment, so I thought it was incompatible.  But it also had the parts for the 2011-3.  Thanks to you, I was able to confirm compatibility and it went smoothly.  I really appreciate your help.

In Japan, I mostly I use Yahoo Auction or Mercari for hunting deals and used gear/parts.   Janpala (stores and online) is good for used items or refurb items.  These sites are all horrible in design, operation, and deal quality, but in the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king.  I found the Thermalright Frozen Edge 240 on Amazon.jp for less than ¥6000.  Rakuten is the worst, although sometimes it's the only place online you can find certain things.

You won't find such. Water blocks need to fit the whole system and it's flow. It's why you can't chop and change parts from different water coolers without serious mods.
You will need to mod a water cooler to fit the backplate, if you cannot remove it.

I'm not sure what you mean.  If some brand like Corsair or CoolerMaster produced a rebranded version of the OEM Asetek 240mm 570LX, then that would use the same attachment assembly (including the same backplate).  I can't search eBay or whatever by Asetek because they don't sell under their own brand.  I need to know the other brands and models that use that same assembly (including, but not limited to, being rebranded Asetek 240mm 570LXs).
